# Pen input jumps across screen when using bamboo ink stylus

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, stylus

When using any application that accepts pen input via a bamboo ink stylus if the cursor is on one side of the screen and I bring the pen down to touch the screen, the cursor will behave as though I dragged a mouse from where the pointer was to where I placed the stylus down.  As shown in this picture: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWL8M.png)

I have tested this behavior and it happens in all of the following applications I have tested:

- GIMP
- Krita
- Xournal

It also exhibits behavior similar to the above (dragging mouse across the screen) in the following applications not intended for pen use:

- Unity Desktop
- Google Chrome
- Entire LibreOffice Suite

I have not found or installed Linux drivers for the bamboo ink stylus.  It is connected via bluetooth and on the bluetooth menu it is listed as a generic input device. My Xorg configurations are the default for Ubuntu 17.04.  Here are my system specifications:

Laptop Model: Dell Inspiron 13-7378

OS Version: Ubuntu 17.04

CPU Model: Intel Core i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz x 4

GPU Model: Intel HD Graphics 620 (Kabylake G2)

Memory: 7.7 GB

OS Type: 64-bit

Disk Size: 251.0 GB

Settings Changed from Default: Display scale set to 1.25

Non-default application installs:

- Krita
- Gimp
- Pitivi
- Google Chrome
- Oracle JVM 8
- GCC and Binutils
- All requirements for the above

Default Applications Removed:

- Firefox

Additional Drivers Enabled:

- Processor Microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the wacom kernel module which has already been fixed in the upstream repository of the [wacom-input project](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom).

[Commit message for the bugfix](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/commit/5181a23c0c11ff59b80df06ec3e897bac660645b#diff-50442bfff81b65825f407b4cacaf047c)

Unfortunately the fix hasn't even made it into Ubuntu 18.04. But fortunately it is straight forward to update the kernel module yourself:

1. Download and extract the last release of the *input-wacom* kernel driver from the github page:

   ```
   wget https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases/download/input-wacom-0.39.0/input-wacom-0.39.0.tar.bz2
   tar xf input-wacom-0.39.0.tar.bz2
   ```
2. Build and install the module:

   ```
   cd input-wacom-0.39.0
   ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```
3. Reload wacom modules:

   ```
   sudo rmmod wacom
   sudo rmmod wacom_w8001
   sudo modprobe wacom
   sudo modprobe wacom_w8001
   ```

(Installation instructions taken from  https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source)

I did not find the solution myself, but this guy did: https://johnbintz.com/blog/2017-12-31-ubuntu-linux-wacom-pen-prox-click/