# Stylus issues on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wacom, stylus

Even though Ubuntu's Wacom setting detects my Wacom Bamboo pad the stylus barely works, and it acts more like a barely functioning mouse than a digital pen. I can only draw faint straight lines after it lags. I'm using the gnome Xorg build as many users suggested in similar situations but the results are the same.  It works on the Unity build but Ubuntu freezes ten minutes after I log in so that's not an option anymore.

Even the Xinput list detects the stylus:

```
themadbaron@themadbaron-desktop:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Pen stylus      id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Finger touch    id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Wireless Bamboo PAD Pen eraser      id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard                              id=17   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
themadbaron@themadbaron-desktop:~$
```

But no luck

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you could try updating the input-wacom driver: https://askubuntu.com/questions/954075/pen-input-jumps-across-screen-when-using-bamboo-ink-stylus/1025202#1025202

Comment: I've followed your suggestion and it didn't work.  I was able to do the first two steps but encountered some errors.   When I tried to reload some files I got this:  rmmod: ERROR: Module wacom is not currently loaded
and this: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wacom': Required key not available
Now Ubuntu doesn't detect both my stylus and tablet  >X(

Comment: should work again after a reboot.

Comment: It still doesn't detect my tablet.   Even putting it on the gedit way didn't help:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/530205/how-to-get-bamboo-pad-working-on-ubuntu-14-04